# How to use regexp to clean data entry errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with numbers that are entered incorrectly in the database and I am trying to remove the data error. Some number values are entered with alphabetical values such as "27.99e". These mistakes I can easily resolve with regexp_replace. However, there are also values entered like this: "14..89" when it should have been entered like this "14.89". I tried to use the reg_exp function to fix it but it is not working, here is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('14..89', '[^.0-9]+', '') from dual;

SELECT regexp_replace(regexp_substr('14..89', '.*(\..*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1), '[^.0-9]+', '') FROM dual;
```

The second one seemed to remove the double period issue, however, it also removed the first half of the number

If someone could please help me, that would be great. Thank you

Comment: For me, 'e' looks like scientific notation and '14..89' looks like a range [14,15,...,88,89]...

Comment: I wonder whether it's a good idea to try to repair the numbers automatically. Sometimes it's better to see the value. If you want to see all strings that Oracle cannot convert into a number, use `where to_number(mystring default null on conversion error) is null`.

Comment: These are wages that people earn so it’s definitely not a scientific notion, sometimes when data is entered manually, unfortunately there are lots of human errors. I have repaired most of it, the only challenge I am facing is that I am having a hard time turning 14..89 to 14.89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         '^([+-])|([eE][+-]?\d+$)|(\.)\.+|[^0-9.]',
         '\1\2\3'
       ) AS cleaned
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '123..45' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '678e' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '+9' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '11-' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12..3+' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '56e-78' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | CLEANED |
> | --- | --- |
> | 123..45 | 123.45 |
> | 678e | 678 |
> | +9 | +9 |
> | -10 | -10 |
> | 11- | 11 |
> | 12..3+ | 12.3 |
> | 56e-78 | 56e-78 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bf663463395e7705688ee063531f688c)*

---

When you have fixed the errors; consider converting the column to a `NUMBER` column so that you cannot enter free text values and get back into this situation.

Comment: @MTO thank you so much! I ended up using this portion of your query: select  REGEXP_REPLACE(‘14..89’, ‘(\.)\.+|[^0-9.]',
         '\1\2\3'
       ) AS cleaned
FROM   table_name  - since I only need the numerical values in either whole or decimal value format without special characters or alphabetical values

Comment: @MTO - just wondering what the 1/2/3 at the end of your query means, if this is a long explanation, please feel free to direct me to a helpful resource I can read. Thank you :)

Comment: @On_demand `\1\2\3` is the value matched by the 1st, 2nd and 3rd capturing groups (in the `()` brackets) in the expression. If you are just using `REGEXP_REPLACE(‘14..89’, ‘(\.)\.+|[^0-9.]', '\1' )` then you only have one capturing group and only need `\1` and don't need `\2\3`.

Comment: @MTO thank you, by capturing group do you mean set of numbers followed by the dot? I tried your formula with only \1 and it gave me the same result as 1\2\3

Comment: @On_demand Yes, it will give the same output as you don't need the `\2\3` if you've removed the capturing groups that they would reference from the regular expression. As I said in the previous comment, a capturing group is something matched inside `()` brackets in the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace more than one dot with exactly one dot:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('14..89', '(\.){2,}', '.') FROM dual;
```

But it doesn't check if you have '1.2.3.4'...

Btw, re 'e' char: are you sure that it wasn't a scientific notation like:

```
SQL> select 28.39e0 as n1, 28.39e4 as n2, 28.39e-3 as n3 from dual;

        N1         N2         N3
---------- ---------- ----------
     28.39     283900     .02839
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you simply **replace** two consecutive dots with a single one?

```
SQL> select replace('14..89', '..', '.') result from dual;

RESULT
----------
14.89

SQL>
```

You don't need regular expressions for that.

Comment: Because this is a large database and there are other errors other than just double dots